# inductive limit

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider spaces 
$$E_n=\{x=\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mid x_j=0,\quad j>n\},\quad x_k\in\mathbb{R}$$ endowed with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norms.

Let $E$ be an inductive limit of these spaces. This set consists of finite sequences.

Is it true that for a basis of neighbourhoods in $E$ one can take sets
$$U_f=\{x=\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mid |x_k|\le f_k\}$$ here $f=\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that the universal property of inductive limits holds. Also, I believe it is better to consider $U_f=\left\{x=(x_k)_k:|x_k|< f_k\right\}$, so that each $U_f$ will be open (this won't hold if we use $\leq$).

First of all, let's verify that the class $\left\{U_f:f=(f_k)_k\subseteq(0,\infty)\right\}$ is a basis for some l.c. (locally convex) topology on $E$: Given $f=(f_k)_k$, $f_k>0$, let $p_f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $p_f(x_k)=\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|x_k/f_k|$. Each $p_f$ is a seminorm on $E$ and $U_f=p_f^{-1}(-\infty,1)$. Also, $p_f^{-1}(-\infty,\varepsilon)=U_{\varepsilon f}$, so $\left\{U_f\right\}$ is a basis for the locally convex topology induced by $\left\{p_f\right\}$.

Hence, we consider $E$ with the topology generated by the sets $U_f$. It remains only to show that the universal property holds:

> If $W$ is a l.c. TVS and $T:E\to W$ is linear and each restriction $T|_{E_n}:E_n\to W$ is continuous, then $T$ is also continuous.

Let $q$ be a continuous seminorm on $W$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we can find $\delta_k>0$ such that if $x\in E_k$ and $\Vert x\Vert_{\infty}<\delta_k$, then $q(Tx)<2^{-k}\varepsilon$.

Consider the sequence $\delta=(\delta_k)_k$. Let $x=(x_k)\in U_\delta$, and choose $n$ such that $x\in E_n$ (since $E=\bigcup_n E_n$). Then we can write $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots)=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$, where $y_i=(0,\ldots,x_i,0,\ldots)$. Notice that $y_i\in E_i$ and $\Vert y_i\Vert_\infty<\delta_i$. Then $q(Tx)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n q(Ty_i)<\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}\varepsilon<\varepsilon$. This shows that $T:E\to W$ is continuous, and thus $E$, with the topology generated by the sets $U_f$, is the inductive limit of the $E_k$'s.